# WPF Databound textbox to display invalid data but NOT accept invalid data

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

I have derived from a textbox and introduced a popup with a calendar and a time picker, this has resulted in a date time picker which works perfectly. Now that, I have a requirement, where in if we need to display an invalid text (apart from date time ) in the date time picker, we should be able to do it, only on load, like if something invalid comes from the database, we should be able to display it.

But if the user tries to enter an invalid value, he should be restricted from doing so.

How can we achieve the same, because I have bound the text property of the textbox to a property of the view model. Also I shall handle the textchanged event. Once the data

Also I have OK, Cancel operations.

I have thought of using a flag, but usage of OK/Cancel puts me in a dilemma, of setting/re-setting the flag too !

Or will the Mode in the binding help ?

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` value to `LostFocus` so that your data bound text property will only see the changes when the user clicks the `OK` `Button`. You should be able to 'reject' an incoming value in the property in this way:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return text; }
    set
    {
        DateTime date;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(value, out date)) // Use whatever condition you like
        {
            text = value;
        }
        else text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This will also clear invalid values from the UI control as `Focus` is lost. However, if using `LostFocus` is not right for you, you can also change your `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` value to `Explicit` and manually call the `UpdateSource` method to update the `Binding`. Please take a look at the [Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) page on MSDN to find out more.

Comment: I shall try this out, and keep you posted!! Thanks for your help !